# How Can I Secure My Video Play Only On My Site

Tags: php, html

I'am planning to play a video on my website, all of my videos are in *videos* folder in my root directory. I have a file named watch.php that will play the requested video. How can I secure my *videos* folder? I don't want other site to just copy my video link and just paste into their site.

**watch.php**

```
<div class="player">
    <video>
        <source type="video/webm" src="secure/testing.webm">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="secure/testing.mp4">
        <source type="video/ogv" src="secure/testing.ogv">
    </video>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this interesting article, where you can learn many strategies to protect your content from hotlinking and abuse [check here](http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/securing-your-content/)